# Fragment Transitions via BottomNavigationView and Nav Graph

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I use navGraph in android with bottomNavigationView and I want to change default transition when clicking navigation items. I created actions like

```
 <action
            android:id="@+id/action_a_to_b"
            app:destination="@+id/fragment_b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_left"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
```

but it uses default fade in/out transition. So my question is how can I use navigation view with nav graph, so that I do not call actions manually, but use them out of box, like I defined it in nav_graph.xml file? When I'm calling

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_a_to_b)
}
```

it works as expected ( transition from left to right/right to left ), but when I just click on navigation item, fade in/fade out transition is called

P.S , I'm using this versions

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit more "how can I...so that I do not call actions manually, but use them out of the box". Also, what kind of transition you are expecting.

Comment: @BadhrinathCanessane, I've edited the question

Comment: So basically, are you asking that you want to navigate to fragment_b without calling  navController.navigate(R.id.action_a_to_b) ?

Comment: yes, actually I'm navigating without calling it, but the transition is not what I want